# Manually create a link to open a file in your IDE (using `framework.ide`)

Tags: symfony, twig

When setting Symfony's [`framework.ide` config option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ide), Symfony adds a link to every file name on its exception pages which allows you to directly open those files in your IDE. Example:

```
atom://core/open/file?filename=...
```

How can I create such a link myself?

Answer (score 0):

**In Symfony controllers & services:**
Just inject `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\FileLinkFormatter`, then do `$fileLinkFormatter->format($filepath, $line)`

**In Twig:**
Create a [custom Twig extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html):

```php
public function ideLink(string $filepath, int $line=0): string
{
    return $this->fileLinkFormatter->format($this->kernel_project_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filepath, $line);
}
```

... and use it like this in a template:

```
{{ ideLink('src/Foo/Bar.php') }}
```